# How to override sendPasswordResetNotification function outside of user model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am doing a password reset and sending email with Notification.
I created ResetPasswordNotification.  I added the sendPasswordResetNotification method inside the User.php model.It works successfully. But since my User model is working in another common project, where can I write the sendPasswordResetNotification method outside of the User.php model.

**my User.php model**

```
   /**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{

    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

In short, how can I use a method other than the user.php model to exclude the sendPasswordResetNotification method in the canResetPassword trait?

Comment: "to exclude the sendPasswordResetNotification method in the canResetPassword trait"  <<<=== can you explain this one more time? You have another User model orrrr another project orrr?

Comment: I have another project. I use the User model in two projects under vendor. It gives an error when there is no notification in the other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project where I use Notification, I opened the user model and extended the common user model and added the sendPasswordResetNotification method there. I produced a solution in this way.